# Getting error while using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm getting an error when I try to execute this statement

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
               (   'CREATE TABLE DP.SD_NEW_TEST TABLESPACE DP_TS_TX_DATA INITRANS   10
                          PARTITION  BY RANGE (SALES_DATE)(
                          PARTITION  '''
                || Partition_name
                || ''' VALUES LESS THAN '''
                || MAX_DATET
                || ''' LOGGING
                        NOCOMPRESS 
                        TABLESPACE DP_TS_TX_DATA INITRANS   10) AS SELECT * FROM DP.SALES_DATA WHERE 1=2'
```

Here Partition_name,MAX_DATET values I'm fetching through other queries as part my procedure . Please suggest if i'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: "An error"?  Any chance you could be more specific than that?

Comment: Put your generated SQL into a variable and output it with `dbms_output.put_line`. This output will help you to understand where you are wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the value of `MAX_DATET` is not formatted in an acceptable way. Basically you need to provide dates as a string with an appropriate data conversion.

The easier thing would be if `MAX_DATET` fitted the ANSI format, `yyyy-mm-dd`. Then all you would need is:

```
            || ''' VALUES LESS THAN date '''
            || MAX_DATET
            || ''' LOGGING
```

Otherwise you'll need to code a `to_date()` call and provide the appropriate mask.

---

Dynamic SQL is hard, because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. As the commenters say, sensible practice here would be to assemble the statement in a variable, which can be displayed through DBMS_OUTPUT. Debugging is always easier when we can see the code which is failing.